# Problem with adist function in text comparison

Tags: r, text, comparison, text-mining, levenshtein-distance

I have a problem with adist function. Basically I am using the example of the RDocumentation.

```
attr(adist(c("kitten", "sitting"), counts = TRUE), "trafos") here
```

However, when I am trying to run added one more word

```
attr(adist(c("kitten", "sitting", "hi"), counts = TRUE), "trafos")
```

I am taking these results:

```
     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     
[1,] "MMMMMM"  "SMMMSMI" "SMDDDDI"

[2,] "SMMMSMD" "MMMMMMM" "SDDDMDD"

[3,] "SMIIIID" "SIIIMII" "MMI"
```

In the third column, third row, I am taking MMI, but I can not understand why as it is the same word "hi". So it has to be MM. (match, match and no insertion)

Reference: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.0/topics/adist

I am using another example:

```
test <- c('x','hi', 'y','x')

attr(adist(test, y=NULL , counts = TRUE), "trafos")
```

I am taking these results. But at least the diagonal needs to be M as is the same word.

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "M"  "SI" "SI" "MI"

[2,] "SD" "MM" "SD" "SD"

[3,] "SD" "SI" "MI" "SI"

[4,] "MI" "SI" "SI" "MI"
```

I can not understand what it is going wrong.

Comment: It seems to me that the string length gets "stuck". I.e, compare `attr(adist(c("ab", "a"), counts = TRUE), "trafos")`, `attr(adist(c("a", "ab"), counts = TRUE), "trafos")`. Must be a bug, right?

Comment: @Axeman That’s what I was thinking. If you just have shorter strings first, it seems fine. Didn’t see that behavior documented though. Thought someone might be able to identify a bug in the source. Just surprised this hasn’t been reported before.

Comment: @MrFlick I guess most people use the other attributes, which seem fine? There are no insertions counted anywhere, even tough the `trafos` list them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have already pointed out it looks like a bug. Using the source from https://cran.r-project.org/src/base/R-3/R-3.5.3.tar.gz and looking at lines **429-432** in file *src/main/agrep.c*, there is code that is reversing a buffer:

```
/* Now reverse the transcript. */
for(k = 0, l = --m; l >= nz; k++, l--)
  buf[k] = buf[l];
buf[++k] = '\0';
```

Walking through what happens in gdb:

```
$ R -d gdb
GNU gdb (Debian 7.12-6) 7.12.0.20161007-git
...
(gdb) b agrep.c:430
Breakpoint 1 at 0x7222e: file agrep.c, line 430.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /usr/local/lib64/R/bin/exec/R
...
R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11) -- "Great Truth"
...
```

Then executing the following R code:

```
> attr(adist(c("kitten", "sitting", "hi"), counts = TRUE), "trafos")

Breakpoint 1, adist_full (x=0x555557995a48, y=0x555557995a48, costs=0x5555561567a8, opt_counts=TRUE) at agrep.c:430
430                                 for(k = 0, l = --m; l >= nz; k++, l--)
```

Continue 8 at the break to reach the last diagonal entry:

```
(gdb) c 8
Will ignore next 7 crossings of breakpoint 1.  Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, adist_full (x=0x555557995a48, y=0x555557995a48, costs=0x5555561567a8, opt_counts=TRUE) at agrep.c:430
430                                 for(k = 0, l = --m; l >= nz; k++, l--)
```

Examine the buffer before reversal:

```
(gdb) x/6c buf
0x5555566a8da0: 83 'S'  73 'I'  73 'I'  73 'I'  77 'M'  77 'M'
```

Stepping through the code shows that `buf[0]` and `buf[1]` are copied from the end of the buffer:

```
(gdb) n
431                                     buf[k] = buf[l];
(gdb) n
430                                 for(k = 0, l = --m; l >= nz; k++, l--)
(gdb) p k
$1 = 0
(gdb) n
431                                     buf[k] = buf[l];
(gdb) n
430                                 for(k = 0, l = --m; l >= nz; k++, l--)
(gdb) p k
$2 = 1
```

Exiting the loop k=2:

```
(gdb) n
432                                 buf[++k] = '\0';
(gdb) p k
$3 = 2
```

And ++k is 3:

```
(gdb) n
433                                 COUNTS(i, j, 0) = nins;
(gdb) p k
$4 = 3
```

Examining the reversed buffer shows that `buf[2]` was not set to NUL:

```
(gdb) x/6c buf
0x5555566a8da0: 77 'M'  77 'M'  73 'I'  0 '\000'        77 'M'  77 'M'
```

This results in:

```
     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] "MMMMMM"  "SMMMSMI" "SMDDDDI"
[2,] "SMMMSMD" "MMMMMMM" "SDDDMDD"
[3,] "SMIIIID" "SIIIMII" "MMI"
```

Replacing `buf[++k] = '\0'` with `buf[k] = '\0'` appears to put the NUL in the correct location:

```
> attr(adist(c("kitten", "sitting", "hi"), counts = TRUE), "trafos")

Breakpoint 1, adist_full (x=0x555557995cb8, y=0x555557995cb8, costs=0x5555561567a8, opt_counts=TRUE) at agrep.c:430
430                                 for(k = 0, l = --m; l >= nz; k++, l--)
(gdb) c 8
Will ignore next 7 crossings of breakpoint 1.  Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, adist_full (x=0x555557995cb8, y=0x555557995cb8, costs=0x5555561567a8, opt_counts=TRUE) at agrep.c:430
430                                 for(k = 0, l = --m; l >= nz; k++, l--)
(gdb) x/6c buf
0x5555566a8da0: 83 'S'  73 'I'  73 'I'  73 'I'  77 'M'  77 'M'
(gdb) n
431                                     buf[k] = buf[l];
(gdb) n
430                                 for(k = 0, l = --m; l >= nz; k++, l--)
(gdb) p k
$1 = 0
(gdb) n
431                                     buf[k] = buf[l];
(gdb) n
430                                 for(k = 0, l = --m; l >= nz; k++, l--)
(gdb) p k
$2 = 1
(gdb) n
432                                 buf[k] = '\0';
(gdb) p k
$3 = 2
(gdb) n
433                                 COUNTS(i, j, 0) = nins;
(gdb) p k
$4 = 2
(gdb) x/6c buf
0x5555566a8da0: 77 'M'  77 'M'  0 '\000'        73 'I'  77 'M'  77 'M'
```

Resulting in the expected output:

```
     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     
[1,] "MMMMMM"  "SMMMSMI" "SMDDDD" 
[2,] "SMMMSMD" "MMMMMMM" "SDDDMDD"
[3,] "SMIIII"  "SIIIMII" "MM"
```

After the fix your second example results in:

```
> test <- c('x','hi', 'y','x')
> attr(adist(test, y=NULL , counts = TRUE), "trafos")
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "M"  "SI" "S"  "M"
[2,] "SD" "MM" "SD" "SD"
[3,] "S"  "SI" "M"  "S"
[4,] "M"  "SI" "S"  "M"
```

The result appears to be consistent with the other attributes for ins, sub and del.

```
> adist(c('x', 'hi', 'y', 'x'), counts=TRUE)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    2    1    0
[2,]    2    0    2    2
[3,]    1    2    0    1
[4,]    0    2    1    0
attr(,"counts")
, , ins

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    1    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    1    0    0
[4,]    0    1    0    0

, , del

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    1    0    1    1
[3,]    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0

, , sub

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    1    1    0
[2,]    1    0    1    1
[3,]    1    1    0    1
[4,]    0    1    1    0

attr(,"trafos")
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "M"  "SI" "S"  "M"
[2,] "SD" "MM" "SD" "SD"
[3,] "S"  "SI" "M"  "S"
[4,] "M"  "SI" "S"  "M"
```

Comment: BTW - the code is the same in the latest 3.6.1 tarball.

Comment: Have you reported this? If not, please do so on the R-devel mailing list (or on Bugzilla if you already have an account there).

Comment: Yes, I filed a bug report here: https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=17579